# Better way of looking for matching value to output result?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a few names I need to check for depending on the number associated with them. Right now I can accomplish this task with the following.

```
$detectInspector = array();
$detectInspector[558]="Name";
$detectInspector[559]="OtherName";
$detectInspector[560]="Someone";

echo $detectInspector[558];
```

The issue is I have hundreds of these I would have to type out. Is there an easier method to perhaps do something like

```
476 through 490 = name
518 through 530 = name
558 through 569 = othername
598 though 609 = othername
650 through 655 = someoneelse
690 through 695 = someoneelse
```

To explain how the code works:

1. Pull number from db
2. Check number against list to see who name
   matches
3. echo result

Comment: You have to give manually a name for each number ?

Comment: Yes, each number is associated with a specific name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

First store your names within a multidimensional array with a name entry and an array with the ranges of the name. Obviously, the name is going to be set if the number is between the min and max value of each range.

```
    $ranges = [
        [
            'name' => 'Jhon',
            'ranges' => [
                [1,50],
                [120,200],
                [401,409]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Jack',
            'ranges' => [
                [20,25],
                [210,230],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Bill',
            'ranges' => [
                [245,270],
                [301,350],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Steve',
            'ranges' => [
                [271,275],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $names = [];
    foreach ($ranges as $nameProps) {
        foreach ($nameProps['ranges'] as $range) {
            list($min, $max) = $range;
            $names[] = [
                'name' => $nameProps['name'],
                'min' => $min,
                'max' => $max,
            ];
        }
    }
```

Then, assuming you get the $nb variable from the db :

```
    $nb = 999;
    $detectInspector = [];


    for ($i = 1; $i <= $nb; $i++) {
        $name = '';
        foreach ($names as $k => $nameProps) {
            if ($i >= $nameProps['min'] && $i <= $nameProps['max']) {
                $name .= ($name ? ' | ' : '') . $nameProps['name'];
            }
        }

        if ($name != '') {
            $detectInspector[$i] = $name;
        }
    }
```

You can now use your $detectInspector value

```
var_dump($detectInspector);
```

Comment: The only issue is while 558 - 569 is one person, 570 - 581 is someone else. Then 598 - 609 is back to the first, and 610-621 is the other. I guess I could set min and max values vs typing each number kinda like you have above.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted